# window.opener.document access denied?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

So, I was hoping you guys could find the logic here?

So after a bit of looking all I've found was access denied errors for the window.opener thing, but it seems to be something else for me. Because I can access that and some of its properties like 'closed'.

I must be doing something wrong here...

My code:

The function that opens it (in a script tag on the parent page)

```
function openPopup(objectID) {
        var webpagina = "Fotos.aspx";
        var param = "objectid=" + objectID + "&edit=true";
        var naam = "Fotos";
        var height = 500;
        var width = 300;
        var top = 250;
        var left = 400;
        var scroll = "Yes";
        var resize = "Yes";

        var newhref = webpagina + "?" + param;

        var popupwindow = window.open(newhref, naam, "toolbar=yes,titlebar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=" + scroll + ",resizable=" + resize + ",width=" + width + ",height=" + height + ",top=" + top + ",left=" + left);
        popupwindow.opener = window;
        popupwindow.focus();
    }
```

The onload function in the opened page:

```
window.onload = function () {
        var isclosed = window.opener.closed; //false
        var secretfield = window.opener.document.getElementById('scrtFoto');
    };
```

The access denied happens on the document, but not the closed, which is false. It's so weird, any help appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the window.opener property, it's automatically set when you open your popup.  Being able to set it manually would be a security risk.

Comment: I know, I was just testing out some things, even without that it doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `contentWindow`.

```
window.opener.contentWindow. document.getElementById('scrtFoto');
```